# How to improve index usage in queries with LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql-like

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id         INT NOT NULL,
    last_name  CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    first_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY `first_name` (first_name),
    KEY `last_name` (last_name),
    KEY `last_first` (last_name,first_name)
);
```

Is it good if i have table index in like that  if i have queries like :

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE first_name = 'A';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name= 'A';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE first_name like '%A%';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name like '%A%';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name= 'A' AND first_name = 'A';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name like '%A%' AND first_name  like '%A%';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name= 'A' OR first_name = 'A';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name like '%A%' first_name  OR like '%A%';
```

UPDATE WRONG QUERY.

Comment: `WHERE %...` can't utilize an index. For all other queries index could help if the table is relatively large.

Comment: so is it good if i have two indeks are contain same field like KEY `first_name` (first_name) and KEY `last_first` (last_name,first_name) ? what do you mean with relatively large ?

Comment: ["index"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index), not "indeks" - also make sure to ask an actual *question*.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE first_name = 'A';
```

Index on first_name will help

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name= 'A';
```

Index on last_name will help

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE first_name like '%A%';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name like '%A%';
```

No index will help, you can only optimise for 'A%' or for '%A' with a column of reversed values.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name= 'A' AND first_name = 'A';
```

Index on lastname,firstname or firstname,lastname will help, but probably on one of them is enough

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE like '%A%' AND like '%A%';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE like '%A%' OR like '%A%';
```

not a valid query

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name= 'A' OR first_name = 'A';
```

Index on either lastname or firstname can help, but good chance of table scan

Comment: SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name= 'A';
Index on first_name will help 
What do you mean indeks on last name ?

Comment: ok , so do you think indeks on first_name and last name without compsoite indeks first_name and last name on  are enough ?

Comment: It depends on many other factors. amount of rows, what other fields you may have and have indexes on. Depends on the country its used in as well, as name search may be culturally different and depending on what people remember. Your question is too generic and doesn't have enough context to give more advice.

Comment: ehm ok
but imagine if it a post table with title and content so whats te good make single index or composite indeks to search in title and or content ?

Comment: you would need a like search in this use case anyway, so an index won't be used.

Comment: i need , in advance search page i use it .
yes i know index not work for LIKE in innodb , but i cant use MYISAM because my website have big data and big traffic , I worry going crash with MYISAM .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61383/discussion-between-reza-daulay-and-jdog).